# Integrating React-Router into a React-Redux hooks app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm having some confusion about how to set up React Router in a redux project. This is a simplification of my top-level component:

```
const App = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = fetchData(); //initial async data fetch
    setData(data);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const initialUsState = getRandomState(data.state);
      const intitialUsCounty = getRandomCounty(data.county);

      //these are action creators that dispatch to the store after the intial data fetch
      dispatchUsState(initialUsState);
      dispatchUsCounty(intitialUsCounty);
    }
  }, data)

  const UsState = useSelector(state => state.UsState); //react-redux state selector hooks
  const UsCounty = useSelector(state => state.UsCounty);

  const getPlotData = () => {
     const plotData = createPlotData(UsState, UsCounty);
     return plotData;
  }

  return UsState && UsCounty ? (
    <Router>
      <Route path={`/:${UsState}/:${UsCounty}`} >
        <ComponentOne UsState={UsState} UsCounty={UsCounty} />
        <ComponentTwo UsState={UsState} UsCounty={UsCounty} />
        <Scatterplot plotData={getPlotData()}
      </Route>
    </Router>
  )
  :
  null;
```

There are a few issues I am having:

1. When I'm running this locally, at `localhost:8080/`, I am not seeing anything being rendered to the screen. I'm assuming this is because I'm at the root level path? How do I get to the `/:${UsState}/:${UsCounty}` path automatically, as soon as `UsState` and `UsCounty` are available?
2. `UsState` and `UsCounty` are both values that live in the store. If I change my url to a specific `/:${UsState}/:${UsCounty}` path that I know is valid, how will the redux be able to dispatch the appropriate `UsState` and `UsCounty` to the store, as well as complete that initial data fetch?
3. Also, if `/:${UsState}/:${UsCounty}` is provided in the URL, I will not want to dispatch a random state & county to the store, as it will already exist in the URL.

Comment: I see a problem in your useEffect. It depends on change in `data` as well as it sets `data`. Doesn't that create infinite loop?

Comment: oh woops, that's a typo above. I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my own question. In top-level index.js, set up the routes in a `<Switch>` component like so:

```
const jsx = ( 
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <CovidApp />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:state/:county">
          <CovidApp />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

When visiting the site for the first time with the exact root directory `/`, in the child component `CovidApp`, I set up a `useEffect()` hook along with the `useHistory()` react-router hook to update the path when either of my redux store values, `UsState` and `UsCounty`, changed:

```
const history = useHistory(); //react-router hook

useEffect(() => {
  if (UsState && county) {
    history.push(`/${UsState}/${county}`);
  }  
}, [UsState, county]);
```

Then, the switch statement above would automatically switch to the `"/:state/:county"` route.

Also in CovidApp, I would check if params already existed when I first navigate to the site. If they do exist, I dispatch them to the store:

```
 const params = useParams(); //react-router hook

 useEffect(() => {
    const urlHasParams = !!Object.keys(params).length;
      //if there are params when first visiting site and data is available: get each param, lookup in dict, and dispatch to store
      if (covidData && urlHasParams) {
        dispatch(dispatchUsState(params.state));
        dispatch(dispatchCounty(params.county));
    }
  }, [data]);
```